# Can I activate a function in a different javascript file than the one I'm trying to activate it from?

Tags: javascript

I've got two javascript files, screenfunction.js and map.js

In screenfunctions.js there's a function that I want to be able to start another function called "go" which is in map.js, is this possible?

This is what's written in the function in screenfunctions.js. The console obviously tells me that "go" is not defined.

```
if (doAnimation == 0){
   go(function(){});
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this in the client (from HTML) or server (node.js)?

Comment: in the client i think

Comment: Then it should just work. Put both `<script>` tags in the HTML, and all the functions should be defined.

Comment: Make sure you load `map.js` before `screenfunction.js`.

Comment: Im not sure why but i've got it exactly like this and i still get "Uncaught ReferenceError"

Comment: Do you have the `defer` or `async` attributes in the `<script>` tags?

Comment: Is the definition of `go` nested inside another function?

Comment: Accessing functions between different files is done all the time. For instance, if you use libraries like jQuery, lodash, or Bootstrap.

Comment: oh yeah it is nested inside another function. can i activate both of them?

Comment: i dont have defer or async in the script tags

Comment: Either don't nest it, or assign the function to `window.go` so it's accessible in the global scope.

Comment: Why do you nest it if you want to be able to call it from outside the function?

Comment: it's just always been nested in the other function, but yeah that wasnt necessary i just found out

Comment: it works now, thanks :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as the required function has already been included beforehand.

There are two ways to do this.

## ECMAScript modules

[Read more about ES modules on the MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Use this if you are writing a server-side application with Node.js (in which case ignore `index.html`), or writing a client-side application for modern browsers. All major browsers have supported ES modules since ~2018, but IE does not support them ([check *Can I use* here](https://caniuse.com/es6-module)).

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script type="module" src="./screenfunctions.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./map.js"></script>
  </head>
  <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

```js
// screenfunctions.js
export function go() {
  console.log('Called go()');
  // ...
}
```

```js
// map.js
import { go } from './screenfunctions.js';

go();
```

## Legacy global declaration

Use this if you are writing a client-side application which must work in older browsers. This approach is worse because the function is declared in the global scope. This could interfere with other code which is also included. This approach is also more prone to breaking because the dependency of the second script upon the first is not obvious at first glance.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script src="./screenfunctions.js"></script>
    <script src="./map.js"></script>
  </head>
  <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

```js
// screenfunctions.js
function go() {
  console.log('Called go()');
  // ...
}
```

```js
// map.js
// `go()` already exists, because `./screenfunctions.js` was included earlier in the markup.
go();
```

Comment: @toonwa I just noticed a mistake in my example. Make sure you include `</script>` if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You'll want to export the function you want to use. See [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#:%7E:text=The%20export%20statement%20is%20used%20when%20creating%20JavaScript,used%20by%20other%20programs%20with%20the%20import%20statement.) for more information and examples.

Comment: That's only needed if they're using node.js, not loading scripts on the client.

Comment: @Barmar This is a MDN link. That's for browsers as you can see at the bottom of the page in the browser compatibility table.

Comment: OK. But you only need to use `export` if you're using `import` to load the file. It's not needed when you just load the file with `<script src="filename.js">`

Comment: @Barmar You can solve the problem using import and export.

Comment: But it shouldn't be necessary. Normally all functions are defined in the same top-level scope.

Comment: @Barmar Using the global scope is prone to errors, though. We shouldn't really teach people that global includes are *the way things should be done*. We have a really good module system in JavaScript now, and browser support is sufficient for most applications; it's a shame not to use it.

Comment: `export` and `import` will put the function in the global scope, won't it?

Comment: Anyway, the question is asking why it doesn't work the way he wrote it. This isn't [codereview.se], we don't normally advise on best practiced.

Comment: `import`ing something will place in the namespace of the including file, but not outside. If there are two things called `go()`, you can import both and give them new names: `import { go as goA } from './a.js'; import { go as goB } from './b.js';`